# How Can I Insert My Javascript Into My Drupal Site/Node

Tags: javascript, drupal, cookies

I'm trying to insert a cookie that is provided by a video host that will resume a video where the user left off. They have an example that obviously works. When trying to insert this into my Drupal site, the cookie won't work. The video just starts back at the beginning.

I have enabled "PHP input filter", as I read that I needed to do that for drupal to insert the script. Please see the code that is in my node below.

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working, how to get it to work, or a better way of doing this with Drupal?

Thank you,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

wistiaEmbed.ready( function() {
  var all_cookies = document.cookie.split(';'), // gets the value of the cookies on the     page
    cookie_str = "resume_video=",
    resume_cookie = does_resume_cookie_exist(all_cookies);


  function does_resume_cookie_exist(cookie_arr) {
    var i, curr_string, found;
      for (i = 0; i < cookie_arr.length; i++) {
      curr_string = cookie_arr[i];
        if (curr_string.substring(0,5) === cookie_str.substring(0,5)) {
          // we've found it!
          found = curr_string;
          break;
        }
      }
    return found;
  }

  function set_cookie_time(t) {  
    document.cookie = cookie_str + t.toString(); // this takes the time (t) and sets the cookie with that time  
  }

  if (resume_cookie) {
    num = resume_cookie.split('=')[1];
    start_time = parseInt(num);
    wistiaEmbed.time(start_time).play(); // plays the video at the specific time defined in the cookie upon return to the page
  } else {
   set_cookie_time(0);  // places a cookie on the visitor
    wistiaEmbed.play();  // starts the video from the beginning
  }
  wistiaEmbed.bind("timechange", function(t) { // on timechange, reset cookie
    set_cookie_time(t);
  });
  wistiaEmbed.bind("end", function() { // if person has watched the entire video, sets the video to beginning upon retun
    set_cookie_time(0);
  });
});
</script>

<div id="wistia_npcc5k96s9" class="wistia_embed"         style="width:640px;height:508px;"> </div>
 <script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="http://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js">  </script>
     <script>
wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("npcc5k96s9");
</script>**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of drupal are you using? Does the code that you gave actually output in your request response?

There are several solutions to this (IMO).

- If the code is showing up in the response, it could be some other javascript error that preventing your code from executing.
- If that snippet of code is applicable to all nodes of that type you can use the node_view hook in order to inject your code on that node type, for example (I am assuming D7):

  ```
  function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode)
  {
      if($node->type =='video_page')
      {
          drupal_add_js('resume_video.js'); // this js holds your code snippet
      }
  }
  ```

  Here's a reference that could help you out
  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7
- You can similarly inject that snippet of code at the theme layer using a theme hook, probably hook_preprocess https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7

Hope that helps.

Comment: I appreciate your input. So would I put that into my html.tpl.php file? Also, I got it to work on my personal site (I'm using it for testing purpose), so I was stoked. Then I inserted the exact script that is working on my personal site into my clients production site and it's not working on my client's production site. Video resumes perfect on my site, but on the clients site it still starts at beginning on revisit. Any ideas? I'm happy to provide you URLs to both so you can see the behavior. Again, thanks! Oh, and I'm D7.

Comment: yes, perhaps a sample link where we can see the faulty code would help.